# oracle apex - how to validate name length with a value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm tring to validate whether the name length is met with the required value or not.

I made a code but it works in a bad way
I'm trying to see the entered name whether is less then 3 or not and return a Boolean to print the message or not.
in some cases the code prevent any entered date and the other is saving the data even if it's less then 3 .

my code is

```
if length(':P11_first_name') < 3 then
return true;
else
return false;
end if;
```

what I need to do to solve this problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should use: `if length(:P11_first_name) < 3 then` without `'`

Comment: "in some cases the code prevent any entered date" - when does it do that, as the condition can never be true? Maybe some other check is involved? I assume 'date' was a typo of 'data', but if it's really a date check then it's not related to what you've shown.

Comment: its data but I wrote it date.. sorry

Comment: If you need just simple check you can use validations: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_validate.htm#HTMDB04018

Answer (score 5):

Don't put the item name in single quotes.  You're checking whether the literal string ":P11_first_name" has a length less than 3.  That string will always be exactly 14 characters.  You want

```
if length( :p11_first_name ) < 3
then
  return true;
else
  return false;
end if;
```

Comment: it shows me this error                                                                                             ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

Comment: Are you sure that you used the code that I posted exactly?  Are you sure that the item `:p11_first_name` exists on the page?

Comment: sir it works! but the return value was wrong it should be flipped .